# Caching the results returned from a stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, optimization, jdbc

Is there a way to cache the results returned from a stored procedures using JDBC, the same like level 1 and 2 cache in Hibernate?

Currently I'm using Sql server, spring and mssql-jdbc. and need to enhance the procedure response time by caching the results in memory for some heavy ones.

I'm calling the stored procedure using the **CallableStatement** with **prepareCall**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring you can use the cache abstraction. See [getting started here.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/)

1) You have to enable caching with `@EnableCaching`

2) You have to annotate the methods that you want to be cached (the repository methods in your case) with `@Cachable`

See full documentations [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).